# Can't read from the source file or disk

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, external-hard-drive, file-transfer

I'm having a two WD external hard disk with capacity of 1 TB. I'm trying to copy `SAP file`(capacity - 250 GB ) in the extension of `.vmdk` from one hard disk to another hard disk.

But when ever i'm trying to copy, at down to the line it showing me this error message.

[image: Failure Message]

By default my both hard disk `File System` value is `NFTS`, even though it showing me an this error message. Is this problem with OS or Hard disk or Data which i'm taken into the action??

What might be the problem, Please give me your suggestions and recommendation.

Awaiting for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up, check that your source hard drive is okay. From a command prompt run the chkdsk command to see if it finds any errors (e.g chkdsk e:  ) Without other parameters it will run in read only mode - it could be that the disk or the data itself has an issue in the last 1% that it is trying to copy.

Do you have enough space on your local machine to copy to your local hard disk? I'm presuming that you are copying from one external disk directly to another.

Does your screen saver or power saving profile come on while the copy is going (i.e. are you leaving your machine unattended during the copy process?) If you have a power saving profile enabled and you leave your machine unattended it may be powering down/disconnecting your external drive.

Finally you could try another copy tool (e.g Roadkil's Unstoppable Copier, Robocopy etc)

Comment: I'm having new 1 TB hard disk, so there is no point lack of storage area here. But, some time i keep my system idle so it went to power save mode. It would case the problem though?? can i make sure, when i run `ckdsk` it won't delete any data from source hard disk?? Because it is having precious data, so i'm having little fear on that.

Comment: if you run chkdsk in read only mode (without parameters other than the drive letter) it will just report any issues found. It won't attempt to fix any errors unless you include parameters such as /f. Run chkdsk without a drive letter will give you the options available for the tool. Power save mode would cause a problem if your power profile disables external devices.

Comment: I have tried Roadkil's Unstoppable Copier tool, it quite shows what is the problem. There was corrupted file lying inside the bulk source file. It was not able to copy last "510.8125 MB" from source.

Answer (score 1):

This error occures when the external disk appears offline for a short period of time while reading. In such cases Windows wouldn't resume reading after the disk becomes available again.

Possible causes include:

- instable USB contact or cable
- instable power supply over USB
- instable HDD controller

Check that all USB connectors are sitting firmly. If you are using the HDD with power supply over USB, it is worth trying a USB-hub with own power supply.

Comment: I'm using External hard disk, it will consume power when it plugged into the computer device.!! Here why i'm getting problem??

Comment: @Wannacoffee - Sounds like a hardware problem.

Comment: @Ramhound: You mean my system/lap or Hard disk??

Comment: I am saying that its likely a hardware failure causing you to be unable to read the file.

Comment: But I have copied some other data also, it can be able to copy well and good.!! The only problem with `.vmdk` extension file.!! Is there any problem with file size ?? Because it is copying up-to 99% at finally it just showing this error.

Comment: If your HDD is powered by your computer, i.e. without separate power supply, chances are good that your computer cannot power the HDD over a extended period of time. Copying small files will be fine, copying a 250 GB file will draw full power for a long time that make it fail.

Comment: @user3767013 - so, what should i do?? is there any option??

Comment: As I said, try to use a USB-Hub with separate power supply, perhaps it can provide more power that your computer.

Comment: having two files in a folder. I can copy paste one of the files in the same folder while for second file it gives this error. Weird...first time experiencing after so many years of Windows usage!!!